# Postgresql is very slow

Tags: postgresql

I try write simple PostgreSQL query from c#. First connection.open() takes 20 seconds. Other connections perform in momently.

PGAdmin work very slow too. If I opened "view all rows" it's takes about 10-15 seconds too (data is very few). Same perform if I opened SQL queries window.

I try this on 2 different computers with win7 and win8. In both machines Postgres work same. So is it normal that PostgreSQL works like this or am I doing something wrong?

I think problem begin from postgresql service running. After postgresql client installed service is running automatically. After some time it's stopped and I can't run it. If I try run service from cmd with pg_ctl I get:

```
FATAL: could not create any TCP/IP sockets
```

And I can connect with pgadmin to postgresql, but it work very slow.

Comment: postgresql is a very capable database. either your machines are super slow | busy with other process or you're doing something wrong.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: Are other SQL clients slow as well? How long does it take to connect using `psql`?

Comment: It's probably not network latency, but just to eliminate the possibility, how long does it take to ping that host?

Comment: Does this help? http://serverfault.com/questions/323356/postgres-connection-establishment-slow

Answer (score 5):

That is not normal.

If the first connection takes 20 seconds and the rest are instantaneous, it sounds like have a DNS problem or some other network problem unrelated to `PostgreSQL` itself.

Answer (score 3):

Try turning off [`log_hostname`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html) in [postgresql.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/config-setting.html) on the server.

> log_hostname (boolean)
>
> By default, connection log messages only show the IP address of the connecting host. Turning this parameter on causes logging of the host name as well. Note that depending on your host name resolution setup this might impose a non-negligible performance penalty. This parameter can only be set in the postgresql.conf file or on the server command line.

Skimmed from [this answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/323358/30039).